# Appcelerator Studio - Unable to run on device but running fine in the genymotion simulator?

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cross-platform, appcelerator

when i run on simulator it is working fine but when i run on device in android it shows the following **error:**

```
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer: Font Cache (CPU):
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   Size: 79.75 KB
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   Glyph Count: 32
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer: CPU Caches:
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer: GPU Caches:
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   Other:
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:     Buffer Object: 63.00 KB (2 entries)
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   SW Path Mask:
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:     Texture: 255.97 KB (3 entries)
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   Image:
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:     Texture: 1.60 MB (5 entries)
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   Scratch:
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:     Buffer Object: 64.00 KB (2 entries)
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:     Texture: 1.00 MB (1 entry)
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:     Render Target: 1.00 MB (4 entries)
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer: Other Caches:
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:                          Current / Maximum
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   VectorDrawableAtlas    0.00 KB /   0.00 KB (entries = 0)
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   Layers Total           0.00 KB (numLayers = 0)
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer: Total GPU memory usage:
[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   4162880 bytes, 3.97 MB (1.97 MB is purgeable)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [4885,4885] Unable to create layer for TiCompositeLayout, size 1024x0 max size 16384 color type 4 has context 1
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
[INFO] :   libc: Requested dump for tid 8724 (Shutdown thread)
[WARN] :   W/com.ava.sample: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder:8724_4
[INFO] :   AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder:8724_4' failed
```

What is the reason and why is it showing this error only on device?

Comment: any code you can show us or describe what you are doing? Are you creating a view that is too big?

Comment: I get the same error, using multiple views with an inputfield in it. SDK 8.0.0 on Android 9. Lower Android versions seem to work.